# Convert Custom Email To PDF : Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, email, custom, pdf

> I Have **Custom Module For Send Email.**
>
> But I Want To Send **Pdf** Same As Email.
>
> I Want To Convert My Email Template To PDF  And **Attach** It to
>   Email **Magento 2.3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

**Define in email_templates.xml :-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="custom_template_id" label="custom_template_id" file="pdftemplate.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**Get Email Template As Html :-**

```
$testTemplate = $this->templateFactory->get('custom_template_id') //template Identifier
                ->setVars($templateVars)
                ->setOptions($templateOptions);

        $html = $testTemplate->processTemplate();
```

**Create PDF :-**

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml($html); //$html is html of template

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

$dompdf->render();
```

Comment: Once this is done, you need to create "addAttachment" method in your transport class.

Comment: public function addAttachment(
        $body,
        $mimeType    = Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename    = null
    ) {
        $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        return $this;
    }